# Remove user from users collection in meteor

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app I have a user listing page and admin should be able to delete users.

```
 Meteor.users.remove({_id:this._id});
```

This is not working. How can I do this ?

Comment: Difficult to say without having any idea of the context or whether this is on the client or server.  However, `Meteor.userId()` will give the logged-in user ID as per [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#method_userId).

Answer (score 1):

Modify `Meteor.users.allow({remove:function() { return true }});` and add in some custom logic there to allow this action only if you're the admin